# Sharing with others without asking for login details

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to be able to share a file from my apple device to any user. It doesn't matter if they have an account or not, they shouldn't be asked to log in or create an account. I've tried using gdrive for Google drive but it keeps crashing. What's the best option I have?

Comment: Wheres the code? Hows crashing? Read the s.o guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.box.com/.  You can edit the permissions for a file so others can access it.  Same as gDrive.  There are other options out there too.  This is just one that is pretty popular.

Here's a link that will help you do this: https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/200520888-Shared-Links-Overview-and-FAQs

Comment: Doesnt seem any different than sharing the file by link in google drive.